# Monitoring battery percentage using Gjs

Tags: gnome-shell, battery, proxy, gnome-shell-extension, javascript

I was looking to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161035/1224351) answer to get an idea of how to get the value of the battery percentage. I modified the example using [this](https://upower.freedesktop.org/docs/Device.html#Device:BatteryLevel) documentation to the following code:

```
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;


// This the D-Bus interface as XML
const batInterface = '<node>\
<interface name="org.freedesktop.UPower.DisplayDevice"> \
    <method name="State"> \
        <arg name="State" type="u" direction="out"/> \
    </method> \
    <method name="Percentage"> \
        <arg name="Percentage" type="d" direction="out"/> \
    </method> \
</interface> \
</node>';

// Declare the proxy class based on the interface
const batProxy = Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper(batInterface);

// Get the /org/freedesktop/UPower/DisplayDevice (the device being displayed I believe) instance from the bus
let batInstanceProxy = new batProxy(
    Gio.DBus.system,
    "org.freedesktop.UPower",
    "/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice"
);

// You can use proxy.<method>Sync syntax to 
// call the D-Bus method in a Sync way
print("The percentage is " + batInstanceProxy.PercentageSync());


let loop = new GLib.MainLoop(null, false);
loop.run();
```

But I am getting this error:

```
(gjs:25859): Gjs-WARNING **: 14:30:15.006: JS ERROR: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.282" (uid=1000 pid=25859 comm="gjs test.js " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.DisplayDevice" member="Percentage" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.40" (uid=0 pid=1226 comm="/usr/lib/upower/upowerd " label="unconfined")
_proxyInvoker@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:139:46
_makeProxyMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:164:30
@test.js:29:47


(gjs:25859): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 14:30:15.006: Script test.js threw an exception
```

On the first line it says `member="Percentage" error name="(unset)"`. Does that mean the member does not exist, or that I just can't access it because of permissions? How can I know?
The device exists, I know because `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice` returns successfully my battery's data. Maybe I messed up with the XML in `batInterface`?

Comment: The command `acpi -bi` gives that info, and it may be easier? Install `acpi` if required.

Comment: Directly reading /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity (or calculating energy_now / energy_full) might be even easier :)

Comment: I want to make an extension that monitors these values. Does it make sense to be reading that once every 5 minutes to get the battery level? seems more logical to have a listener but I don't even know if that is possible. I was trying to learn Gjs for this reason only. @linrunner

Comment: @heynnema Can I excecute acpi in a js script for a shell extension? I'll look into it, thaks for the suggestion